# Call String from one method to another in Java

Tags: java, string, methods, call

sorry if this is a simple question but I have been trying for quite a while now is it possible to call a string from one method to another...

Below I want to call the string `fileName` from the method `fileName` to `fileOutputToFile`. I know I can pass it in but I want to call it from `fileOutputToFile`.

```
public class outputToFile {

    public void fileName(){

         String fileName = "Test";

    }

    public void fileOutputToFile(String hex) throws Exception{

        String fileInfo = hex;

        try {
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                                         new FileWriter("myfile.txt", true)));
                out.print(fileInfo);
                out.print("\n");
                out.close();
            }catch (IOException e){
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify, what is it you're trying to do again?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to call a local variable which is in another method -- it's an issue of scope.

Therefore, it is not possible to retrieve the `fileName` variable from the `fileName()` method from the `fileOutputToFile` method.

One way to "retrieve" the file name would be to `return` the file name when the `fileName` method is called:

```
public String getFileName(){
     String fileName = "Test";
     return fileName;
}
```

(Note: I've taken the liberty to rename the method to something that would be closer to the conventions for naming identifiers in Java.)

Then, in the `fileOutputToFile` method, the `getFileName` method can be called to retrieve the value of the `fileName`.

---

It should be noted that in this case, it may actually be better to just use an field (an instance or class variable) rather than calling a separate method to retrieve a file name. Considering the method is just returning a constant `String`, a field could hold the value:

```
public class OutputToFile {
    // Here, we use a class variable.
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "Test";

    public void fileOutputToFile(String hex) {
        // use FILE_NAME field here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All variables have scope that is generally limited to the {} enclosure that they are in.  So, if you create a variable in one method, it is not accessible in another method unless you pass it in.

The good news is you can create class level variables that are shared by all methods within a class!

```
public class OutputToFile {

    private String fileName = "Test";

    public void fileName() {
           System.out.println(fileName);
           fileName = "Something Different"
    }

    public void fileOutputToFile(String hex) {
           System.out.println(fileName);
           // Do other things with it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to **return** a string from fileName().

Currently, your implementation of fileName() does nothing. You must add a return statement to return a value: 'return "Test"'